# Automatically add project directory to flycheck clang/gcc include path

Tags: projectile, flycheck

I want to use syntax checking with Flycheck in my C++ projects, but the Clang checker fails to find the local file includes. For example, when I have:

```c
#include "foo/bar/x.h"
```

in the file `foo2/y.cc`, it reports an error that it couldn't find the include file. Both `foo/` and `foo2/` are in the project root. I can work around this by adding the following to a `.dir-locals.el` file in the project:

```el
((c++-mode .
     ( (flycheck-clang-include-path . "/home/user/src/myproject") ) )
     ))
```

However, I have dozens of projects and it would be a lot of work to set this for each directory. I'm using Projectile and I think it should be possible to set the include path based on the project root automatically, but I cannot find any variable or function in Projectile that would return the path to the current project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `projectile-project-root` to get the root path and add it to the list with a `c++-mode-hook`

```lisp
(defun setup-flycheck-clang-project-path ()
  (let ((root (ignore-errors (projectile-project-root))))
    (when root
      (add-to-list 
       (make-variable-buffer-local 'flycheck-clang-include-path)
       root)))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'setup-flycheck-clang-project-path)
```

Comment: I don't seem to have a function called "when-let" (symbol's function definition is void). I don't know Lisp very well...how can I replace it?

Comment: I removed the `when-let` and replace it with a `let` and a `when`

Answer (score 1):

You could wait for [this pull request](http://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/pull/661) to get merged. This adds a new `clang-check` based checker to flycheck. The main difference is the tooling supports a [compilation database](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) which contains all the include paths (and defines and other compilation controls) for the file. This database can be automatically created with CMAKE or you can use a tool like [bear](http://github.com/rizsotto/bear) to create it.